# Installing dkms onto an Ubuntu machine that doesn't have a compiler

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel-module, apt, dpkg

I'm trying to install *dkms* onto machines that have no *make* or *gcc*.
I plan to push only binaries to those target machines.

On my build machine I plan to use *dkms* to build *dkms*-enabled modules and then use `dkms mktarball ... --binaries-only` to create tarballs for distribution.

I want to push those tarballs to target machines, and on those machines I
want to use `dkms ldtarball`, and so the target machines do need *dkms*,
but they don't need *gcc* (or *make*).

1. Build (host) and target machines run the same Ubuntu
2. `apt-get install dkms` on the target automatically brings in *gcc*
3. Downloading the *dkms.deb* (`apt-get download dkms`)and installing it with `dpkg --install --ignore-depends=gcc ... dkms.deb`
   does work, but leaves the dependency unresolved so that any future *apt-get* (installing some other package for instance) fails.
4. I can try to use the *equiv* package to create dummy installations of *gcc* and *make*, but this seems like an awful hack I'd prefer to avoid.  Also it could create problems if I ever want to actually install
   gcc on the target in the future.

There's a note about this in the dkms README (section 3), but no guidance on how to accomplish it.
"If you choose not to load module source on your system or if you choose not to load a
compiler ... DKMS can still be used to install modules.".

(sorry if the tags are misleading ... there's no tag available for *dkms*)

Answer (score 0):

Create a local dummy package which pretends to install gcc and any other  deps you want to keep off your system. The [`equivs`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/equivs)  package can be used for this, but it's simple enough to do by hand as well.

Comment: Thanks.  That was my thought too (as I mentioned I tried *equiv*), but then any install later that actually needs *gcc* will skip it (unless I explicitly remove the dummy first).  I was actually hoping there'd be a way create a new dkms<version>.deb that simply doesn't have those dependencies ... sort of a dkms-target-<version>.deb.  Browsing through the *dkms* code, it seems like the target doesn't actually need *gcc* when installing a binary tarball.  The dependency is only there (I think) so that *dkms build* can do it's thing if it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Darik Horn for an excellent (offline) answer.

He suggested using /etc/apt/preferences.d to *pin* the unwanted packages.  That solution looks promising and I will explore further (and post results here if possible).

I was able to find another solution [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=636724) and at [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/280370/how-to-easily-edit-control-file-in-deb-package) which looks promising.

The steps which the script performs can be done manually and are basically this:

1. *mkdir*
2. *dpkg-deb -x dkms...deb*
3. *dpkg-deb --control dkms...deb /DEBIAN*
4. Edit the /DEBIAN/control file *Depends* line
5. *dpkg -b  dkms-modified-...deb*

Comment: The same solution (with working script) is here: http://superuser.com/questions/280370/how-to-easily-edit-control-file-in-deb-package